# How to control div styling from a Wordpress plugin admin meta box

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a plugin meta box (in the Wordpress admin) with the following fields and values:

```
Name of the div class selector= featured_content
Font family= Verdana
Font color= #000
```

These backend fields works perfectly OK and have it fully working and stored in the Wordpress post meta table.

In the Wordpress front end, one of the content template has this div:

```
<div class="featured_content">
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
```

How would I communicate with the Wordpress front end from my Wordpress meta box settings for that div? So that when the page is loaded containing the div class selector name of "featured_content", proper styling would be implemented based on the backend meta box settings. Thank you for any tips.

Comment: I'm finding your question a little unclear. You're saying that the fields for the meta box work, but that the CSS rules aren't being put into effect on the frontend?

Comment: Yes, the meta box work but I don't know how to implement those settings to the front end, how to implement them to its respective div. Do you have some ideas? Thanks Jordy.

Comment: Hmm. Reading your question, it seems like all you would need to do would be to set the "Name of div class selector" to the value of the div's class. Have you used Chrome tools or firebug to see if any CSS rules are being applied, but overridden?

Comment: Yes I already set it, but how to implement them on the front end? Do you know some hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be output a CSS to the front end using the plugin then make that writable..After that the plugin can write whatever CSS rules that it needs to be apply.

The same holds true for JS, etc. I already have this working now.